# jQuery Masonry empty spaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xKjUv/7/) - I need it to dont have free spaces between cubes like it has on example. Just something like Windows 8 tiles or whatever. And I would like to stay with masonry, no isotope, becouse masonry is on MIT licence. Is it possible? I've messed a little with masonry settings but it didnt help so I've cleared it on fiddle.

```
$("#container").masonry();
```

Comment: You want to remove all of the spacing between the cubes?

Comment: You should rephrase your question as it is unintelligible.

Answer (score 6):

You want to change the default column width to 1px,

```
/* JS */   
$("#container").masonry({
    columnWidth: 1,
});
```

otherwise the default is the width of the first element.

Next You should remove the margins

```
/* CSS */
.box-item {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and it should work.

Here is a fiddle of something I think you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/xKjUv/38/